# Problem with Flutter and JSON fetch from server

Tags: json, flutter

I developed app and deployed it in the Playstore. The problem is the app can't fetch JSON file from the server. However, I tested it during development, it is ok. The app can fetch info from the server as normal.

Comment: Can you give us some detail to work from? A minimum verifiable example would help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Do your server logs show an error in the request? Is your app crashing or just failing to retrieve the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you have

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

in the file `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with Proguard file.
Can you show some of the code? I will be able to check it out further.

Mostly when something works during Development and breaks during Release, majorly the problem lies with Proguard.

Just copy-paste some of the code :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comment above. I edited my code by adding permission INTERNET. Also I guess, because of my code:

```
List<Word> parseWord(String responseBody) {
 final parsed = jsonDecode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
  //  String data = utf8.decode(parsed);
  //final parsed = jsonDecode(utf8.encode(responseBody).toString()).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
 return parsed.map<Word>((json) => Word.fromJson(json)).toList();**
}
```

I changed the last line to be :

List  list = parsed.map((json) => Word.fromJson(json)).toList();
 return list;

It works.